# Why can't I place a door?

Tags: 7-days-to-die

I created a house out of `Wood Pillars`, and when I went to place my `Secure Wood Door` and it wouldn't place either direction. I then replaced all the door adjacent `Wood Pillars` with `Wood Frames` and still couldn't place the door.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as a followup, it's not just wood frames, but it has to be a "solid object" that a door can be attached to. This includes things like iron bars, upgraded wooden frames, reinforced concrete, etc. Anything that is removable (wood frames, un-upgraded rebar, etc.) cannot have a door placed around it.

Answer (score 1):

The `Wood Frames` needed to be upgraded past just being frames.